# how to make grid to be 100% after re sizing a browser window?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 2 div elements inside of  but one of them is having class col-md-2 and other is having class col-md-10.[sample view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyQG3.png)

AS shown in image, div containing hyperlinks (Database edit, invoice, preview ) is  not acquiring 100% width. How to make it to acquire 100% width after browser resize?

Comment: try adding `col-xs-12`

Comment: `Database edit, invoice, preview ) is not acquiring 100%` -> `col-md-2`? pls provide some codes. The answer can be anything

Comment: @RahulChandrasekharan Thanks that solved my problem but you should answer in answer section so that i can tick it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the class of your div with `class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2"`. It should works !

Answer (score 0):

Just add a basic CSS media query to expand the width

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
   .col-md-2 {width:100%;}
}
```

Adjust it to your specific needs